# Run Photoshop Script only after all files were opened

Tags: javascript, macos, photoshop

I am trying to make Photoshop tell me how many Files were opened in Photoshop.

Of course I can always go and check in finder, how mnay files I tried to open - but that is not always accurate, sometimes for unknown reason files are skipped. I could also go and count manually, although that takes very long. I've written a simple script which tells me how many file were opened.

```
if (!documents.length) alert("No Open documents");
else alert(documents.length + " images opened");
```

At the moment I simply put it into the action. I open all the files, 200 images, run the action - I receive a pop up message. It is great.

But is there a way to make it automatic? To make the script run only on the last file opened? How would I go about automating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a script to open the files instead of Open command? The script will ask for files location as Open command normally would but in the end you can do whatever you want when files were opened.

```
var inputFiles = File.openDialog(undefined, undefined, true); //multiselect: true
if (inputFiles != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++)
    {
        open(inputFiles[i]);
    }
    alert(documents.length);
}
```

Comment: An interesting suggestion, it does display the count! But it feels a little counterproductive, as It requires to play the action and then navigate to the folder where the files are located. It is more easy to simply open all the files and just play the action once.

Comment: sure, it really depends on what exactly you're looking for

Comment: As in OP - automation. Double-click all files, alert straight away tells you “XX images opened”. Without any extra clicking.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks! It does the job, maybe not necessarily what I was looking for! I managed to implement part of your script somewhere else! Thanks!